# Что означает третье слово в предложении:"На лугу растут цветы"? 1) признак предмета 2) действие предмета 3) предмет

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Что означает третье слово в предложении:"На лугу растут цветы"? 1) признак предмета 2) действие предмета 3) предмет

Comment: Первое слово в этом предложении – "на", второе – "лугу", третье –   **"растут"**... Но явно же это не предмет!

Comment: И не признак: "трын-трава" есть, а "растут-цветы" ботаниками не фиксируются. Остаётся правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Блеск, а не вопрос!

При прямом порядке слов предложение выглядит так:

*Цветы растут на лугу.*

Цветы - подлежащее, растут (что делают - действие "предмета"-подлежащего), на лугу - обстоятельство места (если вопрос "где?") или дополнение (если вопрос "на чём?").

Выбираем вариант № 2: ***действие предмета!***